# ClassNotFoundException (org.postgresql.Driver) with connection pooling example

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling

I am using the sample code found here to implement Connection Pooling  for my webapp: [http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Plain_Ol'_Java](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Plain_Ol%27_Java)

Since I am using PostgreSQL as my database, I changed the line which says `p.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` to `p.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");`.

All I get is a ClassNotFoundException. Where have I gone wrong? Is there any other way?

**EDIT:** If I don't use connection pooling and do the normal way, I don't get the error.

**EDIT 2:** This isn't a duplicate of the suggested question. I am using Eclipse and have the jar included in Build Path and Deployment Assembly. As I said, the error doesn't come when NOT doing connection pooling and just manually opening the connection and closing.

Comment: Have you added the PostgreSQL libraries to your project/classpath/buildpath?

Comment: Yes I have. If I don't use connection pooling and do it normally, I don't get the error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ClassNotFoundException with PostgreSQL and JDBC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891492/classnotfoundexception-with-postgresql-and-jdbc)

Comment: No, this isn't. Please see the updated question. Also, I am using Eclipse and have the jar included in Build Path and Deployment Assembly. As I said, the error doesn't come when NOT doing connection pooling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tomcat 7 expects to find JDBC driver JARs in its /lib folder.  If you put them in your context WEB-INF/lib folder it won't find them and you'll get the error.

The reason it "works" when you don't do connection pooling is that the context class loader can find the JAR.  Tomcat will only go as far as the app server class loader when it's involved.